# Many-to-many relations and foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many, relational-database

As a relative beginner to both Ruby and relational databases, I am working on an update to a model, Log, in a Rails 3 project. A log represents the dropoff of goods from one or more Donors to exactly one Recipient. Both Donors and Recipients are of the class Location.

```
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :donors, :class_name => "Location"
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "Location", :foreign_key => "recipient_id"
  ...
```

And in the relevant migration, I make the tables reflect this:

```
class CreateScheduleChains < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_table :locations do |l|
      l.references :logs
    end
  ...
```

Currently, this is not behaving the way I would like it to; donors still act as though they were related to logs with "belongs_to" - each donor Location can only be associated with a single log, whose id is stored in "log_id". If the migrate reference command is removed entirely, this error occurs whenever a log's donor array is accessed:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column locations.log_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations"  WHERE "locations"."lo...
                                                     ^
: SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations"  WHERE "locations"."log_id" = 1 ORDER BY locations.name ASC
```

Is there any way I can give donors a key to order themselves by while still allowing each donor/location to be associated with more than one log, while allowing each log to have more than one donor?

UPDATE: To clarify, in the current, above implementation, the locations table has a log_id column. I think I need it to instead have a log_ids column (as I thought the has_many relation implied).

Answer (score 0):

change this line in migration **CreateScheduleChains**

```
l.references :logs to

l.references :log
```

which will create a log_id column in **locations** table

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem - the fact that the locations table has a log_id column IS the problem. What I need it to have is something like a log_ids column.

I.e., the existing problem is that a location can only associate with one log, but logs needs to associate with multiple locations (as donors) AND locations need to associate with multiple logs (as donors and a recipient).

Comment: @user3212430 You don't need to have log_ids column since there is has_many defined in model. It's Rails convention. Please have a look at the docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) and you will find your answer.

Comment: I'd worked upon the problem by defining model relationships. Have a look at the code here [http://repl.it/TAg/107](http://repl.it/TAg/107)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :donors, :class_name => "Location"
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "Location", :foreign_key => "recipient_id"
  ...
```

This means you'll need the following `foreign_keys` in your `locations` table:

```
log_id #-> for donors
recipient_id #-> for recipients
```

--

We just use `t.integer` when referencing `foreign_keys` in our migrations:

```
add_column :locations, :log_id, :integer
add_column :locations, :recipient_id, :integer
```

--

[**Associations**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

In light of your comments, you'll probably be best looking at this:

[image]
[image]

This shows you how to set up the relevant `foreign_keys` in your app. Reading that information on the ActiveRecord associations, you'll be able to appreciate how you can better structure your models